# Updating data in foreach loop using ajax in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter, and using foreach loop in a div to display content of the database
here is my code

```
<?php foreach($values as $row): ?>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" id="<?php echo $row->album_id ?>">
<?php echo $row->album_name; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

my question is how can I update the value of "$values" using ajax, and how can I refresh the content of this div.

Comment: you would need to write some client side code that sends an ajax request to the server and some server side code that responds with the data you require

Comment: I know how to write ajax, I want to know how to fetch data in a PHP variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1: 
On PHP side add an action for requesting the values:

```
<?php
$myValues = array(); // maybe from database?
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($myValues);
?>
```

This is your controller action for sending JSON data to the client side.

Step2:
On client-side: (a) add jQuery and then (b) do a ajax call to fetch the data from your action above, like so:

```
$.getJSON( "index.php?getValueAction", function( data ) {
   alert(data);

   // to access the individual properties you would do
   alert(data.property); 

   // use jquery selectors to target the element, where you want the content
   $("#myDiv").append(...);
   // you should create a proper html element before inserting it :)
}
```

The first argument of the getJson() call depends on your Codeigniter routing configuration.
Some have `/index/forum/show`, others have `index.php?controller=forum&action=show`.
Insert the URL style you use, to make the request to CI.

The this answer does the iteration on client-side JS and prepares a dom-element for insertion, right.

--
An alternative would be to keep the PHP part like you have it and send the whole HTML part over on an AJAX request. That's not very nice, but works. Then it's a basic Ajax Get request to the controller/action providing the HTML fragment.

```
$.get( "URL", function( data ) {
   $("#myDiv").html( data );
});
```

Comment: np. You're welcome. I've added an alternative way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [jquery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) with server side processing (using Ajax). There are some [great examples on the data tables site](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).