# Datatable not refreshing on ajax inside each loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Scenario : 
I have a datatable which has checkbox on each row. When i try to select all checkbox and remove all selected data from datatable, it was not refreshing but the code works perfectly fine on the backend. But when i try to select all except 1 row (any of the row) it works fine...

phpaction :

```
$query = "
SELECT id ID, code Code, name Name, description Description FROM tablename WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY id ASC";
$res = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $data = array();
    $tbl = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo json_encode('');
}
```

ajax:

```
$datatable.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
  ID = $(this).attr("value").substr((($(this).attr("value")).length - 8) * -1);
  remove(ID);
});

function remove(ID) {
  requestAction = 'remove';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'phpaction.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      requestAction: requestAction,
      ID: ID
    },
    success: function(data) {
      list();
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641416/updating-data-in-foreach-loop-using-ajax-in-php

Comment: What is the list() function doing?  Are you getting data after each line is removed and keeping track of what was already checked?

Comment: list is for generating datatables

Comment: @DipakDholakiya the code was working perfect.. the primary concern to this was when i try to delete for example 5 out 5 data the datatable was not refreshing(show the 1 undeleted data), but when i try to delete 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 out 4 data the datatable works perfectly